# Python Regex to Extract Word From Multiline String

Tags: python, regex, match, extract, multiline

How would I extract the serial number from the following python string:

```
blah:              asdf
blah:              asdf
Serial Number:     1234ABCD
blah               asdf
blah               asdf
```

I have tried the following, but it doesn't appear to be working:

```
serial_num = re.search("^Serial Number:\s*(\w*)$", serial_num, re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: `print(re.search("^Serial Number:\s*(\w*)$", serial_num, re.MULTILINE).group(1))
` properly extracts 1234ABCD: cannot reproduce your problem...

Comment: I am grabbing the string by using the output of a "subprocess.Popen" command. Perhaps its not a string and that is why I am having trouble extracting it?

Comment: It is definitely a string. I used isinstance(serial_num, str). I'm curious as to why the raw notation isnt working for me. Also, when I try to use the ".group(1)" method I get the following error: "
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may perhaps use the following *regex* ...

```
Serial\sNumber.*?(?=\w)(\w+)
```

see **[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UsaYqx/1/)**

**python** ( [demo](https://ideone.com/DDZ1hp) )

```
import re

s = """
blah:              asdf
blah:              asdf
Serial Number:     1234ABCD
blah               asdf
blah               asdf
"""
r = r"Serial\sNumber.*?(?=\w)(\w+)"
m = re.findall(r, s)
print(m)[0]
```

Comment: So the actual string is coming from running the following command: serial_num = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/FastCli","-c","show version"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]. I am doing this from an Arista switch. I'm beginning to wonder if the output of that subprocess command isnt clean. I tried your solution and it didnt work on that string.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a string that doesn't work?

Comment: Whoops! The actual output of the switch "show version" command used "Serial number" and not "Serial Number". I was able to get this solution to work. For whatever reason I wasn't able to get my original regex to work though.

Comment: @ChrisWillis Glad it worked! BTW, an accept would be much appreciated tho :-)